# What is the formula for the Mean & Variance for this Log Normally Distributed Variable

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean, random-variable, lognormal-distribution

[image]

I am having trouble finding the mean and variance for this log normal distribution.

Comment: Wikipedia gives expressions for the mean and variance of a [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), i.e. for $\frac{c_{t+1}}{c_t}$

Comment: if $X$ is lognormal $E(X^t)$ is not hard to do by evaluating the integral (you can get what you want from $t=1,2$), but easier still is to obtain it directly from the MGF of $\log(X)$ (a normal distribution), assuming you've already done (or otherwise have) that calculation. I believe some answers on site already have the result.